# How to fill the record TpagesetupDlg with printer's info other than default in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, printing

I am desperately searching for how to provide a non-default printer's information to API functions like `StartDoc()`, `StartPage()`, etc without invoking the dialog box.

I found that I must fill `TPageSetupDlg` or `TPrintDlg` with appropriate values (especially the `devNames` structure), but I don't know how.

edit

I have write this code that works but it doesn't change the orientation to landscape as i want. Probably i haven't fill the devMode structure right.

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonXClick(Sender: TObject);
type
    TdevNames = record
        wDriverOffset : WORD;
        wDeviceOffset : WORD;
        wOutputOffset : WORD;
        wDefault : WORD;
    end;

    TdevMode = record
        dmDeviceName : array[0..CCHDEVICENAME-1] of char;
        dmSpecVersion : WORD;
        dmDriverVersion: WORD;
        dmSize: WORD;
        dmDriverExtra: WORD;
        dmFields : DWORD;

        dmOrientation : short;
        dmPaperSize : short;
        dmPaperLength : short;
        dmPaperWidth : short;
        dmScale : short;
        dmCopies : short;
        dmDefaultSource : short;
        dmPrintQuality : short;

        dmColor : short;
        dmDuplex : short;
        dmYResolution : short;
        dmTTOption : short;
        dmCollate : short;
        dmFormName : array[0..CCHFORMNAME-1] of char;
        dmLogPixels : WORD;
        dmBitsPerPel : DWORD;
        dmPelsWidth : DWORD;
        dmPelsHeight : DWORD;

        dmNup : DWORD;
       dmDisplayFrequency : DWORD;
    end;

var
    DocInfo: TDocInfo;
    devNames : TdevNames;
    aDC : hDC;
    devMode : TdevMode;
    str1, str2 : string;
const
    DOC_NAME = 'Stack Overflow';
    FILE_NAME = 'test.xps';
    MAX_PATH = 260;
begin
        devMode := default(TdevMode);
        devMode.dmSize := sizeof(TDEVMODE);
        devMode.dmPaper.dmOrientation := DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
        devMode.dmFields := DM_ORIENTATION;
        aDC := createDC('',pchar('Microsoft XPS Document Writer'),@devMode,0);
        DocInfo := Default(TDocInfo);
        DocInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(DocInfo);
        GetMem(DocInfo.lpszDocName, 32);
        GetMem(DocInfo.lpszOutput, MAX_PATH);
        lStrCpynW(DocInfo.lpszDocName, DOC_NAME, Length(DOC_NAME) * sizeof(char));
        lStrCpynW(DocInfo.lpszOutput, FILE_NAME, Length(FILE_NAME) * sizeof(char));
        StartDoc(aDC, DocInfo);
        StartPage(aDC);
    str1 := 'page 1';
    str2 := 'page 2';
        TextOut(aDC, 100, 100, pchar(str1), length(str1));
        EndPage(aDC);
        StartPage(aDC);
        TextOut(aDC, 100, 100, pchar(str2), length(str2));
        EndPage(aDC);
        EndDoc(aDC);
        FreeMem(DocInfo.lpszDocName, 32);
        FreeMem(DocInfo.lpszOutput, MAX_PATH);
        shellExecute(application.Handle,'open',FILE_NAME,'','',SW_MAXIMIZE);
        deleteDC(aDC);
end;
```

Comment: The APIs in question require an `HDC` to the desired printer device.  Use `CreateIC()` or `CreateDC()` to get that `HDC`.  The dialogs simply provide a convenience to choose a printer and initialize the VCL's `TPrinter` singleton with the appropriate `HDC`. You could just set the `TPrinter.PrinterIndex` property and then read the `TPrinter.Canvas.Handle` to do the same thing (but then you might as well use the `TPrinter.Canvas` for all of the printing).

Comment: Remy thanks for your reply.
Your suggestion uses the Tprinters unit. I used this approach since now but i faced the problem that printing to XPS it pops up the "saveAs" dialog that i don't want because i want to save to a predefined filename.
So somebody told me to print without using the TPrinters unit. But now i must bypass the TPageSetupDlg or TPrintDlg.

Comment: You don't have to use the `Printers` unit, that is provided as a convenience, not a requirement. `StartDoc()`, `StartPage()`, `Create(IC|DC)()`, these are Win32 API functions, and the Win32 API has no concept of the VCL. Have you read MSDN's [Printing documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686805.aspx) yet? There is even an [API for XPS printing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316976.aspx).

Comment: Can you provide a code snipet about prepare the canvas (create hDC with XPS filename and XPS printer), please ?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation I linked to.  And no, StackOverflow is not a translation service, so please don't ask us to translate the examples to Delphi for you. Please try to translate them yourself, or find a 3rd party translation tool to do it for you. If you run into problems, ask specific questions about that.

Comment: Remy, no i didn't ask to translate something. But i stuck.
I create a record TdevMode, I set dmOrientation := DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE and create the hDC like this : aDC := createDC('',pchar('Microsoft XPS Document Writer'),@devMode,0);
Then i draw some text on the aDC but the orientation of the XPS is portrait. That's why i ask you some code snipet.
Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: You keep adding information here in the comments that should really be in your post where they can be seen. Don't expect people to wade through a lot of comments to pick out the useful pieces. Spend some time on a decent [edit] of your question and make it clear what you're asking and what you've tried.

Comment: Ken, I'm not a such experienced programmer as you, nor my english are good. That's why i'm asking your help and maybe i'm not understandable some times. Be more patient, please.

Comment: @JimPapas: Why are you manually declaring the `TDevNames` and `TDevMode` record types? You should be using the existing declarations in Delphi's `Winapi.CommDlg` and `Winapi.Windows` units, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be declaring the `TDevNames` and `TDevMode` record types manually.  Use the existing declarations in Delphi's `Winapi.CommDlg` and `Winapi.Windows` units, respectively.

You are also calling `CreateDC()` incorrectly.  In fact, your code should not even compile, as you are passing a `PDEVMODE` where a `PChar` is expected, and passing an `Integer` where a `PDEVMODE` is expected.

You should also be checking API calls for errors.

Try something more like this instead:

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.Windows, Winapi.CommDlg;

procedure TForm1.ButtonXClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lDocInfo: DOCINFO;
  lDevMode: DEVMODE;
  lDC: hDC;
  str: string;
const
  DOC_NAME = 'Stack Overflow';
  FILE_NAME = 'test.xps';
begin
  lDevMode := default(DEVMODE);
  lDevMode.dmSize := sizeof(lDevMode);
  lDevMode.dmFields := DM_ORIENTATION;
  lDevMode.dmOrientation := DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;

  lDC := CreateDC(nil, 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer', nil, @lDevMode);
  if lDC = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to open printer');
  try
    lDocInfo := Default(DOCINFO);
    lDocInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(lDocInfo);
    lDocInfo.lpszDocName := DOC_NAME;
    lDocInfo.lpszOutput := FILE_NAME;
    if StartDoc(lDC, lDocInfo) <= 0 then
      raise Exception.Create('Unable to start print document');
    try
      if StartPage(lDC) <= 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('Unable to start a new print page');
      str := 'page 1';
      TextOut(lDC, 100, 100, PChar(str), Length(str));
      EndPage(lDC);
      if StartPage(lDC) <= 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('Unable to start a new print page');
      str := 'page 2';
      TextOut(lDC, 100, 100, PChar(str), Length(str));
      EndPage(lDC);
      EndDoc(lDC);
    except
      AbortDoc(lDC);
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    DeleteDC(lDC);
  end;
  if ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', FILE_NAME, nil, nil, SW_MAXIMIZE) < 32 then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to open printed file');
end;
```

If it still fails to print in landscape, then the problem is with the XPS driver itself, not with the code.

Comment: Thanks again Remy. Meanwhile i had found my errors and that structures are already declared in delphi's units. I was able to print correctly (except the error checking).
Now i'll dig for more eg for margins etc.